# AdMob ads not showing in iOS

Tags: ios, admob, codenameone

AdMob ads are not showing for iOS builds in the last couple of days. It used to work and I didn't change anything.

- iOS - 9.3.5
- IDE - NetBeans 8.0.2
- CodenameOne Plugin - 3.5.2
- OS - Windows 7

Comment: when you say it's not showing. does it fill rate issue? kindly share logs

Answer (score 1):

Google deprecated the old admob library and discontinued it. We need to update to the latest version for ads to keep working. We plan on updating the cn1lib within the near future, I'm assuming that is the implementation you are referring to.

Comment: Which old versions of AdMob were deprecated?

Comment: I was thinking about the answer from Carlos: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/DeqKJQx_rgk

Comment: I'm talking about the banner ads. These are still showing in Android but nor showing in iOS.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the same issue expressed in banner ads due to changes to google play services. You can file an issue on this but I think the right solution would be to move this to an external cn1lib like the interstitial ads.

Answer (score 1):

AdMob ads are not showing because for iOS 9 http URL’s are blocked by Apple. They show up by using the build hint

```
ios.plistInject=<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/></dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/DeqKJQx_rgk

Based on that the deadline is September 15, so your problem isn't related to this.