# GoogleAds Doesn't show up

Tags: codenameone, ads

In my CodenameOne project I defined google ads' unit ids for both android and ios. There is no problem with the android version. But in the ios version the ads do not show up, although it did for a while, it stopped suddenly. Any ideas where I can check what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check your ad unit id is active or not.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39753120/756809 I'm not sure if it's the right answer but it seems to be related to the HTTPs limits from Apple: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I put the built hint

Comment: just as it is in the properties dialog?

ios.plistInject=<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/></dict>

Comment: That's the idea

Comment: Nothing helps. Below my settings file:

'codename1.arg.ios.project_type=ios
codename1.ios.provision=
codename1.arg.android.googleAdUnitId=ca-app-pub-111/222
codename1.arg.ios.googleAdUnitId=ca-app-pub-333/444
codename1.arg.ios.statusbar_hidden=false
codename1.languageLevel=5
codename1.vendor=CodenameOne
codename1.arg.ios.prerendered_icon=true
libVersion=135
codename1.arg.ios.plistInject=<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/></dict>
codename1.packageName=com.dagsoft.appl.tagiest
codename1.arg.ios.testFlight=true'

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

when copying ios.plistInject=NSAppTransportSecurity‌​NSAllowsArbitraryLoa‌​ds from websites and pasting it to properties dialog some extra chracters are copied also, something like that: NSAllowsArbitraryLoa**\u200C\u200B**ds Removing them solves the problem